# Json data not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have fullcalendar with some JSON data. It shows up as "12a Medical Day Jackson Post". Otherwise the display is fine. When I change the dates to be "start":"12/2/2015" to this 2015-2-12. The 12a appen disappears.

The Code for fullcalendar used is this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek'
            },
            defaultDate: '2015-03-11',
            defaultView: 'month',
            selectable: false,
            selectHelper: false,
            select: function(start, end) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                var eventData;
                if (title) {
                    eventData = {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end
                    };
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            if (view.name !== 'agendaDay') {
            $(jsEvent.target).attr('title', event.title);
            }
            },
events:[ 
  {
    "title":"Medical Day Jackson Post",
    "start":"12/2/2015",
    "end":"12/3/2015",
    "description":"Jackson"
  },
```

Comment: You want the 12a or not? (it stands for 12AM)

Comment: I do not want the 12a. Is that a bug or do I have to edi the JS files to remove it? I am uncertain

Answer (score 0):

By default it shows the time unless the event is an [`allDay`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) event. If `allDay` isn't specified, it guesses and in your case, it guessed differently depending on the date format.

So, either make `allDay` explicit in you events, or stop the time from displaying on all events with `timeFormat: "",` as one of you fullCalendar options.